# How to change Django model field from Integer to Decimal field for Postgres DB?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, sqldatatypes, django-model-field

I'm trying to change the data type of a Django model field from PositiveBigIntegerField() into DecimalField().

From:

```
quantity=models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
```

To:

```
quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

But when I migrate the change, it shows the following Postgres DB error:

```
Numeric field overflow Detail: A field with precision 8, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^6.
```

is there any idea how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to go into the shell and make sure non the current quantity values stored are more than 8 digits and 2 decimal places. If so, change them, and try again

Comment: From the docs [Numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL): *The precision of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point. The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point.*.  This means with a `decimal_place/scale` of `2` the longest integer that would work is `6` digits long. I'm guessing  you have bigger  integers then that.  Do `select max(int_fld) from table` to see how big.

Comment: @Nealium, actually precision of 8 means the total number of digits on either side of the decimal point.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I was just going off the Django field, not the postgres error. 8 numbers total, two of them are decimals places. digit == numbers in my mind

Comment: Examples: `select 12345678::numeric(6, 2); ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 6, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^4.` **vs** `select 12345678::numeric(10, 2); 12345678.00`.